# Android RenderScript relationship with OpenGL ES shading language

Tags: android, opengl-es

what's the relationship between RenderScript of Android and OpenGL Shading Language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no relationship between Renderscript and the OpenGL ES shading language. Renderscript is a C99-based language for accelerating compute workloads across a wide variety of devices. GL ES shader language is a restricted C-like language that is primarily used for graphics.